# How to choose the metric value when evaluating the performance of a deep learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, metric, testing

When evaluating the performance of a deep learning model (for the purpose of publishing a research work), should we choose the optimal value from the metric curve (such as the accuracy curve) or the convergence value? I think sometimes the optimal value is a result of randomness. So I'm not sure if it can reflect the actual performance of a model. For example, in the accuracy-epoch curve below, should I choose the optimal value (highlighted by the red circle) as the model performance?
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking if you should use the model that corresponds to the optimal metric (e.g. accuracy in this case), right?

Comment: @nbro Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

In short: you should provide the optimal (best) value, but this is not the whole story.

As you said:

> I think sometimes the optimal value is a result of randomness.

This is perfectly true. Therefore, if you want to provide high-quality research results, you *should NOT* consider the single best value due to randomness. You may have been just luck, and got a very high value which, in reality, can be a very rare training run.

What you should do is to *train the model multiple times* according to your computational budget: when the dependence on random numbers is not too strong, even $3$, $5$, or $10$ training runs (with different random seeds) are enough for statistically relevant results. But when randomness is an issue, like in reinforcement learning, way more runs (even 100+) may be necessary.

In this way you can aggregate the result by *mean* (i.e, average expected performance of your model class) and *stddedv* (expected deviation from optimal model.) Doing so, you can obtain much more reliable results.

- Another option is to plot the results with associated *error bars*, such that the wider the bar is the more the variance is.
- A further one, is to get a *p-value* (by comparing the distribution of results) which is interpreted as the probability that method (or algorithm) A beats method B.

(b.t.w. I also assume your training and evaluation setups are mostly, if not entirely, *reproducible* - i.e., deterministic given a fixed random seed.)

As a side fact: is also important to train until your model converges, so until the learning curve stabilizes around a certain value (which is the best one so far, or very close.) This is important to check that both your model and training procedure is healty.